# Tidy up dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have been given a dataset that looks something like this:

```
title                  topic
building something     3       alice    roy      jane
taking a break         5       stanley  bernard  alice   jane
how to make a cake     2       stanley  robert
playing by the pool    3       robert   alice
```

And I will need to tidy it up to be in such a format:

```
                  topic
name        1   2   3   4   5
alice       0   0   2   0   1
bernard     0   0   0   0   1
jane        0   0   1   0   1
robert      0   1   1   0   0
roy         0   0   1   0   0
stanley     0   1   0   0   1
```

May I ask how I can do so using pandas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['names'] = df['names'].str.split()
df['topic'] = df['topic'].str.strip()
df = df.explode('names')
df['val']=[1]*len(df)
df.pivot_table(index='names', columns='topic', values = 'val', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value = 0)
```

Complete code:

```
#Prepration
string='''title     topic     names
building something     3       alice    roy    jane
taking a break         5       stanley  bernard  alice   jane
how to make a cake     2       stanley  robert
playing by the pool     3       robert   alice'''
data = [x.split('     ') for x in string.split('\n')]
#Main part
df['names'] = df['names'].str.split()
df = df.explode('names')
df['val']=[1]*len(df)
df.pivot_table(index='names', columns='topic', values = 'val', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value = 0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
```

Output:

```
topic   2   3   5
names           
alice   0   2   1
bernard 0   0   1
jane    0   1   1
robert  1   1   0
roy     0   1   0
stanley 1   0   1
```